# regarding Certificate fingerprints selection for google authentication in android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, rsa-key-fingerprint

I am trying to implement google authentication in my android app. To implement Google Sign In option in android app `SHA1` is needed to generate `OAuth 2.0 client IDs`.

I am using ubuntu and here is the process how I am retrieving `Certificate fingerprints`

I typed the following commands

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security
keytool -list -keystore cacerts -v
```

Then I found the following output

```
    Your keystore contains 177 entries

    Alias name: debian:pscprocert.pem
    Creation date: Jan 30, 2016
    Entry type: trustedCertEntry

    Owner: CN=PSCProcert, C=VE, O=Sistema Nacional de Certificacion Electronica, OU=Proveedor de Certificados PROCERT, ST=Miranda, L=Chacao, EMAILADDRESS=contacto@procert.net.ve
    Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=acraiz@suscerte.gob.ve, OU=Superintendencia de Servicios de Certificacion Electronica, O=Sistema Nacional de Certificacion Electronica, ST=Distrito Capital, L=Caracas, C=VE, CN=Autoridad de Certificacion Raiz del Estado Venezolano
    Serial number: b
    Valid from: Tue Dec 28 22:51:00 BDT 2010 until: Sat Dec 26 05:59:59 BDT 2020
    Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX       
         SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
         SHA256: XX:XX:XX...
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: debian:ca_disig_root_r2.pem
Creation date: Jan 30, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=CA Disig Root R2, O=Disig a.s., L=Bratislava, C=SK
Issuer: CN=CA Disig Root R2, O=Disig a.s., L=Bratislava, C=SK
Serial number: 92b888dbb08ac163
Valid from: Thu Jul 19 15:15:30 BDT 2012 until: Sat Jul 19 15:15:30 BDT 2042
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX       
         SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
         SHA256: XX:XX:XX...
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

********************************
********************************
********************************
and other Certificate fingerprints
```

As the keystore contains 177 entries, which one should I use for google API keys and OAuth 2.0 client IDs.

Previously I was using the last `SHA1` but it was not working for me to autheticate the app. I am very much confused about it. Please suggest something. Why I am getting these too many **Certificate fingerprints entities**?
I appreciate your help and advice. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but your post is a little vague. By *I am not able to do it*, pertaining to the Google Authentication, are you encountering any errors? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @sept I have updated my question and added details.